# Determine if UITouch is within SKLabelNode frame

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uitouch, sklabelnode

My goal is to find out if a UITouch took place within a SpriteKit label node. The view is an SKView. The issue with the code that I am using (below) is that the touch and the rectangle seem to be in different coordinate systems.

I could use simple math to correct this, but is there a simple way to correct this issue? Or is there another way I should be doing this?

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for t in touches {
        let position = t.location(in: view)

        //if inside startButton
        if (startButton?.frame.contains(position))! {
            debugPrint("yes")
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is your `startButton` contained directly in the view that receives touches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are are overriding `touchesBegan` within a scene. If so, then try using `let position = t.location(in: self)`, i.e. replace `view` with `self`. That way you get the position within the scene itself, rather than the position within the view that holds the scene.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I had thought that `view` and `self` would be the same for this case, but obviously I misunderstood. What exactly is the difference between `view` and `self` in this particular case?

Comment: By default the origin of the scene (`self` in this case) is bottom-left corner, while `view` has its origin in the top-left corner. So a positive y in `position` means you "go up the screen" using scene coordiantes. The same y value for `position` would mean you "go down the screen" using view coordinates.